# Unselect other check box when selecting one check box

Tags: html, angular, typescript, checkbox

In my scenario, I have 2 checkboxes. By default, both checkboxes can be false or 1 check box is true and other is false or vise versa.

User should be able to **select only one checkbox and if he wants he can de-select both**. Further, default values are selected using another field. if that field is empty Checkbox is false and vise versa.

**NOTE**

I have achieved what I want but the code looks ugly. Can anyone suggest me a clean way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" name="cb1" (click)="unselectCheckbox()" [(ngModel)]="cb1">
<input type="checkbox" id="cb2" name="cb2" (click)="unselectCheckbox()" [(ngModel)]="cb2">
```

TS

```
  cb1 = false;
  cb2 = false;

  public unselectCheckbox() {  
    if (this.cb1) {
      this.cb2 = false;
    } else {
      this.cb1 = !this.cb1;
      this.cb2 = false;
    }
    if (this.cb2) {
      this.cb1 = false;
    } else {
      this.cb1 = !this.cb1;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
 <input
      type="checkbox"
      id="cb1"
      name="cb1"
      (change)="unselectCheckbox($event, 'checkbox1')"
      [(ngModel)]="cb1"
    />
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      id="cb2"
      name="cb2"
      (change)="unselectCheckbox($event, 'checkbox2')"
      [(ngModel)]="cb2"
    />
```

TS

```
public unselectCheckbox(event, opt) {
    console.log(event.target.checked);
    if (opt == 'checkbox1') {
      this.cb1 = event.target.checked;
      this.cb2 = false;
    }
    if (opt == 'checkbox2') {
      this.cb2 = event.target.checked;
      this.cb1 = false;
    }
  }
```

In HTML,(change) event value passed two parameters to TS.

This looks clean I think.